# Is there a Rails callback on activity creation that is available for caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, getstream-io

I'm looking for some sort of callback that is sent when a new activity is created. Ideally, it would include some information about which user's feed has a new notification.

The workflow goes something like this: once a new activity is created, I would receive a callback, proceed to clear the fragmented cache, and finally prewarm a new cache.

Is there a callback or some response when an activity is created with the `stream_rails` gem?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What is this "activity" that you talk about?

Comment: In this case, it's a notification, for the notification feed of a particular user. It could be a comment, article, follow, etc, that creates a new activity/notification. Just following Stream's vocab; activities are from the `stream_rails` gem.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is a `concern`, that has an `after_create` callback, and is included in all the models that you consider `activity`.